# Python, random words into questions

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
wordlists1 = ["hot","summer", "hard", "dry", "heavy", "light", "weak", "male",
             "sad", "win",  "small","ignore", "buy", "succeed", "reject", "prevent", "exclude"]

wordlists2 = ["cold", "winter", "soft", "wet", "light", "darkness", "strong", "female", "happy", "lose", "big",
         "pay attention", "sell", "fail", "accept", "allow", "include"]
```

I use random.choice to pick a word from each list. Once I have the words, I need to print them as a question. For e.g., if hot and weak are selected it should print: "Hot is to cold as weak is to___?"

I really need help on this, and detailed steps would be appreciated.

My code:

```
import random 

wordlists1 =["hot","summer", "hard", "dry", "heavy", "light", "weak", "male", "sad", "win", "small","ignore", "buy", "succeed", "reject", "prevent", "exclude"] 
wordlists2 =["cold", "winter", "soft", "wet", "light", "darkness", "strong", "female", "happy", "lose", "big", "pay attention", "sell", "fail", "accept", "allow", "include"] 
randomword1=random.choice(wordlists1) 
randomword2=random.choice(wordlists2)
```

Comment: Show us the code you have so far, even if it's broken.

Answer (score 4):

I might do something like

```
>>> wpairs = list(zip(wordlists1, wordlists2))
>>> example, question = random.sample(wpairs, 2)
>>> "{} is to {} as {} is to ?".format(example[0], example[1], question[0])
'small is to big as summer is to ?'
```

---

First, I'd combine the two lists into a list of pairs:

```
>>> wpairs = list(zip(wordlists1, wordlists2))
>>> wpairs
[('hot', 'cold'), ('summer', 'winter'), ('hard', 'soft'), ('dry', 'wet'), ('heavy', 'light'), ('light', 'darkness'), ('weak', 'strong'), ('male', 'female'), ('sad', 'happy'), ('win', 'lose'), ('small', 'big'), ('ignore', 'pay attention'), ('buy', 'sell'), ('succeed', 'fail'), ('reject', 'accept'), ('prevent', 'allow'), ('exclude', 'include')]
```

And then I'd use `random.sample` to choose two of them:

```
>>> example, question = random.sample(wpairs, 2)
>>> example, question
(('weak', 'strong'), ('heavy', 'light'))
```

One major advantage of using `random.sample` here is that you don't have to worry about drawing the same pair twice (no "weak is to strong as weak is to ?" questions.)

After this, we can make a question string:

```
>>> "{} is to {} as {} is to ?".format(example[0], example[1], question[0])
'weak is to strong as heavy is to ?'
```

Comment: This is clearly the best answer. Using sample in this manner avoids the case of sampling the SAME element twice, which is possible in the  answers where sample/choice is called twice.

Answer (score 2):

```
wordlists1 = ["hot","summer", "hard", "dry", "heavy", "light", "weak", "male",
                     "sad", "win",  "small","ignore", "buy", "succeed", "reject", "prevent", "exclude"]

wordlists2 = ["cold", "winter", "soft", "wet", "light", "darkness", "strong", "female", "happy", "lose", "big",
                 "pay attention", "sell", "fail", "accept", "allow", "include"]

import random

t = zip(wordlists1, wordlists2)
t1, t2 = random.sample(t, 2)
print '%s is to %s as %s is to ___? (%s)' % (t1[0], t1[1], t2[0], t2[1])
```

Shoould print something like 
`dry is to wet as ignore is to ___? (pay attention)`

**Update**: I switched to `random.sample(t, 2)` from `random.choice`. It's the better way to do this. (As Suggested by DSM, but I wanted to update my code as well).

Answer (score 1):

You used `random.choice` twice, which makes `randomword1` different from `randomword2` in terms of position in your lists. Use `random.randint` instead to get a unified index each time:

```
import random 
wordlists1 =["hot","summer", "hard", "dry", "heavy", "light", "weak", "male", "sad", "win", "small","ignore", "buy", "succeed", "reject", "prevent", "exclude"] 
wordlists2 =["cold", "winter", "soft", "wet", "light", "darkness", "strong", "female", "happy", "lose", "big", "pay attention", "sell", "fail", "accept", "allow", "include"] 
idx1 = random.randint(0, len(wordlists1)-1)
idx2 = random.randint(0, len(wordlists1)-1)
words_to_choose = (wordlists1[idx1], wordlists2[idx1], wordlists1[idx2], wordlists2[idx2])
print '%s is to %s as %s is to ___? (answer: %s)'%words_to_choose

#OUTPUT: reject is to accept as exclude is to ___? (answer: include)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random 
wordlists1 =["hot","summer", "hard", "dry", "heavy", "light", "weak", "male", "sad",      "win", "small","ignore", "buy", "succeed", "reject", "prevent", "exclude"] 
wordlists2 =["cold", "winter", "soft", "wet", "light", "darkness", "strong", "female",     "happy", "lose", "big", "pay attention", "sell", "fail", "accept", "allow", "include"]
l1=len(wordlists1)
index1=int(random.random()*l1)
index2=int(random.random()*l1)
myquestion=wordlists1[index1]+" is to "+wordlists2[index1]+" as "+ wordlists1[index2]+"    is to___?"
print myquestion
```

Answer (score 1):

Using random choose two word indexes and with those indexes generate question and check if the answer is correct or not like this:

```
import random
def makeQuestion():
    indexes = range(len(wordlists1))
    word1 = random.choice(indexes)
    word2 = random.choice(indexes)
    ans = raw_input("{} is to {} as {} is to___? ".format(wordlists1[word1], wordlists2[word1], wordlists1[word2]))
    if ans.strip().lower() == wordlists2[word2]:
       print True
    else:
       print False
```

Demo:

```
>>> wordlists1 = ["hot","summer", "hard", "dry", "heavy", "light", "weak", "male",
...              "sad", "win",  "small","ignore", "buy", "succeed", "reject", "prevent", "exclude"]
>>> wordlists2 = ["cold", "winter", "soft", "wet", "light", "darkness", "strong", "female", "happy", "lose", "big",
...          "pay attention", "sell", "fail", "accept", "allow", "include"]
>>> import random
>>> def makeQuestion():
...     indexes = range(len(wordlists1))
...     word1 = random.choice(indexes)
...     word2 = random.choice(indexes)
...     ans = raw_input("{} is to {} as {} is to___? ".format(wordlists1[word1], wordlists2[word1], wordlists1[word2]))
...     if ans.strip().lower() == wordlists2[word2]:
...        print True
...     else:
...        print False
... 
>>> makeQuestion()
succeed is to fail as sad is to___? happy
True
>>> makeQuestion()
prevent is to allow as ignore is to___? pay attention
True
>>> makeQuestion()
exclude is to include as heavy is to___? cold
False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import randint

wordlists1 = ["hot","summer", "hard", "dry", "heavy", "light", "weak", "male",
             "sad", "win",  "small","ignore", "buy", "succeed", "reject", "prevent", "exclude"]

wordlists2 = ["cold", "winter", "soft", "wet", "light", "darkness", "strong", "female", "happy", "lose", "big",
         "pay attention", "sell", "fail", "accept", "allow", "include"]

index1 = randint(0, len(wordlists1) - 1)

index2 = randint(0, len(wordlists2) - 1)

answer = wordlists2[index2]

print ("Q : %s is %s as %s is to ________ ? " % (wordlists1[index1], wordlists2[index1], wordlists1[index2]))

user_input = raw_input("A : ")

if user_input.lower() != answer:

        print ("Answer is %s" % answer)
else:

        print ("Correct Answer")
```

Answer (score 0):

generate a random number from 0 to length of your lists. This number would represent choosing a random index from your lists. Once you have "randomly" chosen your words, just use them in your questions

Answer (score 0):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import random

__author__ = 'lve'

wordlists1 = ["hot", "summer", "hard", "dry", "heavy", "light", "weak", "male",
              "sad", "win", "small", "ignore", "buy", "succeed", "reject", "prevent", "exclude"]

wordlists2 = ["cold", "winter", "soft", "wet", "light", "darkness", "strong", "female", "happy", "lose", "big",
              "pay attention", "sell", "fail", "accept", "allow", "include"]

answer_string = ''

random_question_index = random.randrange(len(wordlists1))

answer_string += '{} is to {} as '.format(wordlists1.pop(random_question_index).capitalize(), wordlists2.pop(random_question_index))

random_answer_index = random.randrange(len(wordlists1))
answer_string += '{} is to___? \nAnswer is {}'.format(wordlists1.pop(random_question_index),
                                                      wordlists2.pop(random_question_index).upper())
print(answer_string)
```